# Sagemaker-huggingface An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Requested image not found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface

I'm trying to create an asyncronous sagemaker endpoint as shown here [shown here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/async-inference/Async-Inference-Walkthrough.ipynb) but using a huggingface model, so I need to use one of the huggingface images and for that I check the official list of available options [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg-ecr-paths/ecr-us-east-1.html) but when trying to create a model based on that, I get the error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Requested image 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-training:1.9.1-transformers4.12-gpu-py38-cu111-ubuntu20.04 not found.
```

I tested like 3 options from the official list and none worked(not even the example shown in that page works). But using the exact same code, just changing to xgboost and it's corresponding version works, so I know it has something to do specifically with this images, any ideas or suggestions on where to find the list of supported huggingface images?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a old container which may be out of support can you try changing to latest huggingface container images from this URL and see if it works

https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md#huggingface-inference-containers